# Using Scala Pickling serialization In APACHE SPARK over KryoSerializer and JavaSerializer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo, scala-pickling

While searching best `Serialization` techniques for `apache-spark` I found below link
https://github.com/scala/pickling#scalapickling
which states `Serialization` in `scala` will be more faster and automatic with this framework.

And as `Scala Pickling` has following advantages. (Ref - https://github.com/scala/pickling#what-makes-it-different)

So, I wanted to know whether this `Scala Pickling` (`PickleSerializer`) can be used in `apache-spark` instead of `KryoSerializer`.

- If yes what are the necessary changes is to be done. (Example would be helpful)
- If No why not. (Please explain)

Thanks in advance. And forgive me if I am wrong.

Note : I am using `scala` language to code `apache-spark` (Version. 1.4.1) application.

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer @Sam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I visited Databricks for a couple of months in 2014 to try and incorporate a `PicklingSerializer` into Spark somehow, but couldn't find a way to include type information needed by scala/pickling into Spark without changing interfaces in Spark. At the time, it was a no-go to change interfaces in Spark. E.g., RDDs would need to include `Pickler[T]` type information into its interface in order for the generation mechanism in scala/pickling to kick in.

All of that changed though with Spark 2.0.0. If you use `Dataset`s or `DataFrame`s, you get so-called `Encoder`s. This is even more specialized than scala/pickling.

**Use `Dataset`s in Spark 2.x. It's much more performant on the serialization front than plain RDDs**

Comment: Thanks for reply @Heather Miller But Currently I am using apache-spark 1.4.1 and Kryo serialization. So I think I have to continue with the same only :(